# How to deal with repeated letters in a java hangman game?

Tags: java

I am really confused on dealing with repeated letters in my java hangman game e.g. there are multiple 'a's in the word 'banana', but my program only deals with the first 'a' and leaves the other 'a's out. Other than that, the program works fine with word with no repeating letters e.g. 'brush'. This there any solutions to deal with repeated letters? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hangman{

public static void main(String []args){
Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String[] CollectionOfWords = {"","gravity","banana","gate","processor","momentum","earth","star","light","television","pan","cupboard"};

    int radmNumber = (int) Math.ceil (Math.random() * CollectionOfWords.length);
    int counter = 10;
    String radmWord = CollectionOfWords[radmNumber];

    char[] genRadmLetter = radmWord.toCharArray();
    char[] genRadmLetter2 = radmWord.toCharArray();
    for (int x = 0; x<genRadmLetter.length; x++){
        genRadmLetter[x]='?';
    }

    System.out.println(String.valueOf(genRadmLetter));
    System.out.println("Hello. Guess a letter.");
    char guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
    int RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);

    if (RW >= 0 ){

    genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
    System.out.println(genRadmLetter);

    }

    if (RW == -1){
        System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
        counter = counter - 1; 
        System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
    }

    while (counter != 0) {

        System.out.println("Guess a letter.");
        guessedLetter = Input.next().charAt(0);
        RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);

        if (RW >= 0 ){

        genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
        System.out.println(genRadmLetter);
    }

        if (RW == -1){
        System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
        counter = counter - 1; 
        System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
    }

        boolean result = Arrays.equals(genRadmLetter, genRadmLetter2);
        if (result == true){
            break;
        }

        if (counter == 0){
            break;
        }

    }

    if (counter == 0){
        System.out.println("You lose. The word was: " + radmWord);
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Well done, you have guessed the word.");
        System.out.println("Your final score is: " + counter);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Use List instead of arrays, and use `List#contains`. In Java you should rarely use arrays.

Comment: You need to loop over the _whole_ array. You shouldn't use `indexOf` as that, as you rightly point out, only finds the first index.

Comment: `indexOf` returns the index of the *first occurrence* of the specified Character in a String. You probably want to call `indexOf` in a loop until it's -1 to gather all occurrences. You can use `indexOf(char, fromIndex)` for this.

Comment: but the indexOf doesn't seem to work for char arrays? Even after I done the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop, so while RW != -1, and use [indexof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29), from the previous RW.

Something along this line:

```
if (RW == -1){
        System.out.println("Wrong letter, try again.");
        counter = counter - 1; 
        System.out.println("Lives left: " + counter);
} else {
        System.out.println(genRadmLetter);
        while (RW >= 0 ){
            genRadmLetter[RW] = guessedLetter;
            RW = radmWord.indexOf(guessedLetter, RW+1); 
        }
}
```

This is to get it working on the same way that you tried. You could have use other ways, keeping the entries as string and using replaceAll.

Another point, is you do a check outside your first while loop, you could put it inside to write less code and make it more clear.